# Title service in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have used the Tile service of Angular, and title are getting set successfully.
Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private titleService: Title) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.setTitle('homepage first title');
  }

}
```

but the problem is that when i check the title change through "view page source", none of the changes are getting reflected and the default title in index page is showing , what can i do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

View page source is the plain `index.html` source file (like you have it on your/server file system). No JavaScript is executed or anything, so obviously nothing will show.

If you would like to have that the application is already compiled, take a look at [NgUniversal](https://github.com/robwormald/ng-universal-demo/), to leverage server side rendering. Not sure if that will work for your use-case though.